# name student undefined in python for class creation

Tags: python, class

New to python. While running this script in python, I am getting an `undefined name: student` error. Below is my code. I tried solving this but failed.

```
class Student:
    Std1 = Student()
    #std2 = Student()

    Std1.fname='Sushant'
    Std1.lname='Shinde'

    print(Std1.fname)
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a class Student that will make an object called `Std1`? If so you will need to review where you are making the object.  Ill try and post and example.

Comment: All your code is outside any methods (`def my_method(): ...`) so it gets executed as part of *defining* the class, not instantiating it or anything

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: @ZackTarr That link is for this page

Comment: You should get a basic understanding of how classes work. Google `python class tutorial` and click on any of the links. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) is a link to the Python docs.

Comment: @PulkitAgarwal whoops! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer, I would recommend looking for a Python OOP tutorial. [This one](https://python.swaroopch.com/oop.html) (not my website) looks okay.

---

You are trying all of your operations in the scope of `Student`.
You should try something like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):  # self is a reference to the newly created object
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

Std1 = Student('Sushant', 'Shinde')  # Create an instance object, with specific fname and lname
print(Std1.fname)  # Sushant
Std1.fname = 'Sushant2'
print(Std1.fname)  # Sushant2

Std2 = Student('Another', 'Student')
print(Std2.fname)  # Another
print(Std2.lname)  # Student
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

Std1 = Student()
#std2 = Student()

Std1.fname='Sushant'
Std1.lname='Shinde'

print(Std1.fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Class is basically a blueprint for the objects and you have to define a class for student before creating objects for it.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname;
        self.lname = lname;


Std1 = Student('Sushant', 'Shinde')
print(Std1.fname)
```

`__init__(self)` is function that acts as constructor and holds the attributes or member variable of the class. Above is right way to use class. For further reference you can read about class and objects [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use class properties.

```
class Student:
    fname = 'a'
    lname = 'b'

print(Student.fname)
a = Student()
print(a.fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code is a class definition, you define the attributes and behavior of the class `Student`.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,first,last):
       self.first_name = first;
       self.last_name = last;

    def show_full_name(self):
       print(self.first_name+" "+self.last_name);
```

The function `__init__` is the function that will be called just after you create an object of `Student`, for example..

```
student_A = Student("Ali", "Miles");
student_B = Student("Sarah", "Parker");
```

After this, you can use the *attributes*: `first_name` and `last_name`. You can also use the defined *method*: `show_full_name` to show the object's full name.

```
student_A.show_full_name();
student_B.show_full_name();

print(student_A.first_name);
print(student_B.first_name);
```

Output of the above 4 lines code :

```
Ali Miles
Sarah Parker
Ali
Sarah
```